# Determine the proper level of heteroskedasticity

Tags: heteroscedasticity, multivariate-regression

My dependent variable is house prices and I need to understand whether the level of heteroskedasticity in this plot of residuals vs fitted values is low enough to accept the existing multi-variate regression model without manipulations. I appreciate any suggestions.[image: residuals vs fitted values]

Comment: What is the goal of your model?

Comment: @David, It is a hedonic pricing model to determine the effect of house characteristics on its sales price.